# How to access a static field from a class passed as a parameter to a function in Java?

Tags: java, function, static, field

```
    public class Parameter {
        public static int my_static_int;
    }



    public class Test {            
        public void foo (Class<Parameter> argument) {
            argument.my_static_int = 1; 
    }
```

When I type this code, Eclipse gives me an error when I try to access my_static_int in the function foo, saying `my_static_int cannot be resolved or is not a field`. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The static modifier in Java is directly related to the class. If the field is static, it means that it belongs to the class. Based on this, you can access a static method or field using the class name.

In your case, you can access the field directly:

```
Parameter.my_static_int
```

Comment: The problem is that in my actual code I have to pass the class as a parameter in order to access a static field from many different extensions of the class. How could I manage to do so?

Comment: Static means that it is the same for all instances (objects) of the class.